# How to properly check if a name is available in an array made of objects (record collection)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object, for-loop

so my plan for this was to have a message appear asking someone to type in a student name. Javascript would look through a record, which is in a seperate JS file, and then output that in the message variable. If suppose the student didn't exist, the output message would be the alert box in the else statement.

Heres a record of the students:

```
var students=[
    {
        name:'Chris',
        track:'IOS',
        achievements:'100',
        points:'1000'
    },
    {
        name:'John',
        track:'Web Design',
        achievements:'90',
        points:'1000'
    },
    {
        name:'Brent',
        track:'Front-End',
        achievements:'70',
        points:'1000'
    },
    {
        name:'Josh',
        track:'Full-Stack',
        achievements:80,
        points:'1000'
    },
    {
        name:'Nick',
        track:'AI',
        achievements:'60',
        points:'1000'
    }
];

var message="";
    var search=prompt("Type name of student");
    while (search!=="quit") {
      for (var i=0; i<students.length; i+=1) {
        var studentName=students[i].name;
        if (studentName===search) {
          message+="<h1>"+studentName+"</h1>";
          message+="<p>"+student[i].track+"</p>";
          message+="<p>"+student[i].achievements+"</p>";
          message+="<p>"+student[i].points+"</p>";
          break;
        } else {
                alert("That student does not exist. Try again");
                break;
        }
        }
        search=prompt("Type name of student");
    }
    print(message);
```

When I try this code, it asks me for the student's name and then says he/she is not available. Apparently, the determination that the student is not in the list should only be made after the loop has finished checking all the students. Then, and only if nothing was found, should the failure message be output.

The problem for me, conceptually, is that the final value of the variable, studentName, after the for loop ends will be the name property of the last object in the array. So how would I redesign my for loop then?

How can I redesign my code to accomplish just that?

Comment: why are you prompting the user for every iteration of your loop?

Comment: Take a look at this: [Creating closures in loops: A common mistake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops_A_common_mistake)

Comment: Add a flag that determines whether a match was found or not. Set it to true in your loop if a match is found. After the loop is finished, check the status of the flag and do the respective action.

Comment: Yes, you are quite close. First thing, `students` array is missing in your codepen code. Secondly, for the problem, yes you are right. To resolve this, you can save the index, when you find a match. And later after the loop, you can directly fetch the object from the array using the index to have access to its other properties.
Also, you can add a `break` in your loop as soon as you find a match, so that there are no unnecessary iterations.

Comment: It's up to you. You can keep it to resolve your if condition after the for loop, or initialize index to `-1` and check it's value instead. If it's greater than -1, meaning there was a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,

```
var message="";
    var search=prompt("Type name of student");
    while (search!=="quit") {
    // we will get result if any one student name matches
    var result = students.find((student) => student.name === search);
    if (result) {

          message+="<h1>"+result.name+"</h1>";
          message+="<p>"+result.track+"</p>";
          message+="<p>"+result.achievements+"</p>";
          message+="<p>"+result.points+"</p>";
    }
    else {
        alert("That student does not exist. Try again");
    }
        search=prompt("Type name of student");
    }
    print(message);
```

Comment: Array.prototype.find() method is used to find a first element in an array that satisfies the condition given in call back function. => means arrow functions. Here is the detailed explanation of arrow function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

you can filter your list first and then check it like

```
   const students = [
    {
        name: 'Chris',
        track: 'IOS',
        achievements: '100',
        points: '1000'
    },
    {
        name: 'John',
        track: 'Web Design',
        achievements: '90',
        points: '1000'
    },
    {
        name: 'Brent',
        track: 'Front-End',
        achievements: '70',
        points: '1000'
    },
    {
        name: 'Josh',
        track: 'Full-Stack',
        achievements: 80,
        points: '1000'
    },
    {
        name: 'Nick',
        track: 'AI',
        achievements: '60',
        points: '1000'
    }
];

let search = prompt('Type name of student');
while (search !== 'quit') {
    const filteredList = students.filter(function(student) {
        return student.name === search;
    });

    let message = '';
    if (filteredList.length > 0) {
        for (const student of filteredList) {
            message += '<h1>' + student.name + '</h1>';
            message += '<p>' + student.track + '</p>';
            message += '<p>' + student.achievements + '</p>';
            message += '<p>' + student.points + '</p>';
        }
        alert(message);
    } else {
        alert('That student does not exist. Try again');
    }
    search = prompt('Type name of student');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid looping through the entire array each time you want to show a message for the user, making an object from the array is the best approach.

for example:

```
var students=[
    {
        id: 1,
        name:'Chris',
        track:'IOS',
        achievements:'100',
        points:'1000'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name:'John',
        track:'Web Design',
        achievements:'90',
        points:'1000'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name:'Brent',
        track:'Front-End',
        achievements:'70',
        points:'1000'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name:'Josh',
        track:'Full-Stack',
        achievements:80,
        points:'1000'
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        name:'Nick',
        track:'AI',
        achievements:'60',
        points:'1000'
    }
];

const arrayToObject = (array) =>
   array.reduce((obj, item) => {
     obj[item.id] = item
     return obj
   }, {});

const studentsObject = arrayToObject(students);

console.log(studentsObject);
console.log(studentsObject[2]);
```